# Why my list does not show up?

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-7, grid

I have a list of Grids and not show in my page, and the debugger shows nothing. Ive tried to do this in the xaml but didn't worked too. Anyone can help me?

PS. My classes are fine and my `stcList` exists.

```
List<Grid> listaGrids = new List<Grid>();

        List<HyperlinkButton> listaLinks = new List<HyperlinkButton>();

        int i = 0;

        AppDataContext db = new AppDataContext();

        Pessoa pessoa = db.Pessoas.Single(c => c.Email == email);

        foreach (Coletor coletor in pessoa.Coletores)
        {
            if (coletor.Ativado == true)
            {
                Grid aux = new Grid();
                ColumnDefinition c1 = new ColumnDefinition();
                ColumnDefinition c2 = new ColumnDefinition();
                ColumnDefinition c3 = new ColumnDefinition();

                aux.Width = 400;
                aux.Height = 80;

                aux.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

                c1.Width = new System.Windows.GridLength(280);
                c2.Width = new System.Windows.GridLength(80);
                c3.Width = new System.Windows.GridLength(80);

                coletorAux = coletor;

                aux.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c1);
                aux.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c2);
                aux.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c3);

                RowDefinition r1 = new RowDefinition();

                aux.RowDefinitions.Add(r1);

                HyperlinkButton aux2 = new HyperlinkButton();
                aux2.Content = "Coletor " + (i + 1).ToString();
                aux2.FontSize = 34;
                aux2.NavigateUri = new Uri("/OcorrenciasPage.xaml?coletorId=" + coletor.Id.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                i++;

                Button btnEdit = new Button();

                var brush = new ImageBrush();

                brush.ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("/icons/edit.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

                btnEdit.Background = brush;

                btnEdit.Width = 80;
                btnEdit.Height = 80;

                btnEdit.Click += btnEdit_Click;

                Button btnDelete = new Button();

                ImageBrush brush2 = new ImageBrush();

                brush2.ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("/icons/delete.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

                btnDelete.Background = brush2;

                btnDelete.Width = 80;
                btnDelete.Height = 80;

                btnDelete.Click += btnDelete_Click;

                Grid.SetColumn(aux2, 0);
                Grid.SetColumn(btnEdit, 1);
                Grid.SetColumn(btnDelete, 2);
                Grid.SetRow(aux2, 0);
                Grid.SetRow(btnEdit, 0);
                Grid.SetRow(btnDelete, 0);

                listaGrids.Add(aux);


            }
        }

        ListBox coletores = new ListBox();
        coletores.ItemsSource = listaGrids;
        stcList.Children.Add(coletores);
```

Comment: Oh, no no no no no.  Lawd no.  Noooo nononono.  Stop what you're doing, go read up on MVVM.  You're doing 100x the work you need to, and you're going to have 1kx the number of bugs doing it.

Comment: What is MVVM? Can you leave a link to me? I really want this to work.

Comment: Go search on MSDN for MVVM.  Good luck.

Comment: Your grids probably don't show up because you are creating them but not displaying them. You need to set the grid as your page content, maybe this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/resources/676/how-to-create-a-grid-in-wpf-dynamically.aspx) can help. But yes, Will is absolutely right, you should not be making grids programmatically unless if you absolutely have to. MVVM is a design pattern that will make what you're trying to do a lot easier to code and maintain.

Comment: @gitsitgo Thanks, your link helped me and now it is working fine. About the MVVM, I am watching a tutorial but will take a time to me to understand and implement in my app because I am new in MVVM.

Comment: @GustavoMendonça yep take your time. It took me a while to understand MVVM too, but if you use it in future projects I can guarantee you your code will be a lot cleaner and easier to manage.